# Export R data.frame to SPSS

Tags: r, csv, export, spss

There is a package `foreign` with a function `write.foreign()` that can write a SPS and CSV file. The SPS file than can read the CSV fiel into SPSS including labels. Fine so far, but there are some issues with that function:

1. Newer SPSS versions may show an error that you have too few format definitions in `DATA LIST`
2. If there are "labels" for numeric variables stored via `attr()`, these are lost.
3. Even if the SPSS vesion supports strings up to 32767, the function `write.foreign()` stops if there are more than 255 in any variable.
4. Theres a star (*) if any character variables are used, but newer SPSS versions cannot handle that.
5. The CSV file is comma-separated and does (can) not use quotes, therefore no commas are allowed in strings (character)
6. Non-ASCII caracters (e.g. umlauts) will crash the import
7. Should you have a character that contains any NA value, you'll see...

... an error message like this:

```
Error in if (any(lengths > 255L)) stop("Cannot handle character variables longer than 255") : 
    missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I spent a lot of time with that and then found a good posting (http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/SPSS-export-in-R-package-foreign-td921491.html) to start on and make it better. Here's my result, I'd like to share with you.

Answer (score 29):

To export an R data.frame to SPSS, use `write_sav` from the haven package:

```
library(haven)
write_sav(mtcars, "mtcars.sav")
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Factors and POSIXct are exported fine as well. This would definitely have saved me a lot of time... And it's vary fast. Minor drawbacks I found with my test data set: Comments are not exported as variable labels, strings are clipped to 255 characters, and if there are strings with exactly 255 chars, it sometimes creates a SAV file that won't open in SPSS (at least version 23).

Comment: Glad it helped.  If you have a reproducible example to document the phenomena, and believe it can be fixed, you could post an issue on the package's [GitHub repository](https://github.com/tidyverse/haven/issues).

Comment: Yes, actually I spent some time to track the issue :) reported at https://github.com/tidyverse/haven/issues/226

Answer (score 2):

This function is a replacement for `foreign:write.foreign` to handle the issues stated above.

**Note:** To avoid issues with SPSS finding the CSV file, please specify the full path (!) at least for `datafile` (also if using the original `foreign:write.foreign()`).

**Note:** This script will replace a tabulator (TAB) and other spacing (incl. CR+LF) in strings by a blank without warning. One may consider using `GET DATA` instead of the troublesome `DATA LIST` to solve that limitation.

**Note:** There may be a warning `In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : probable complete loss of accuracy in modulus` - this refers to counting the decimals and can be ignored.

**Note:** `POSIXlt` and `POSIXct` variables are not yet handled by the script properly.

```
writeForeignMySPSS = function (df, datafile, codefile, varnames = NULL, len = 32767) {
    adQuote <-  function (x) paste("\"", x, "\"", sep = "")

    # Last variable must not be empty for DATA LIST
    if (any(is.na(df[[length(df)]]))) {
        df$END_CASE = 0
    }

    # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5173692/how-to-return-number-of-decimal-places-in-r
    decimalplaces <- function(x) {
        y = x[!is.na(x)]
        if (length(y) == 0) {
            return(0)
        }
        if (any((y %% 1) != 0)) {
            info = strsplit(sub('0+$', '', as.character(y)), ".", fixed=TRUE)
            info = info[sapply(info, FUN=length) == 2]
            if (length(info) >= 2) {
              dec = nchar(unlist(info))[seq(2, length(info), 2)]
            } else {
              return(0)
            }
            return(max(dec, na.rm=T))
        } else {
            return(0)
        }
    }

    dfn <- lapply(df, function(x) if (is.factor(x))
        as.numeric(x)
        else x)

    # Boolean variables (dummy coding)
    bv = sapply(dfn, is.logical)
    for (v in which(bv)) {
        dfn[[v]] = ifelse(dfn[[v]], 1, 0)
    }

    varlabels <- names(df)
    # Use comments where applicable
    for (i in 1:length(df)) {
      cm = comment(df[[i]])
      if (is.character(cm) && (length(cm) > 0)) {
        varlabels[i] = comment(df[[i]])
      }
    }

    if (is.null(varnames)) {
        varnames <- abbreviate(names(df), 8L)
        if (any(sapply(varnames, nchar) > 8L))
            stop("I cannot abbreviate the variable names to eight or fewer letters")
        if (any(varnames != varlabels))
            warning("some variable names were abbreviated")
    }
    varnames <- gsub("[^[:alnum:]_\\$@#]", "\\.", varnames)
    dl.varnames <- varnames
    chv = sapply(df, is.character)
    if (any(chv)) {
        for (v in which(chv)) {
            dfn[[v]] = gsub("\\s", " ", dfn[[v]])
        }
        lengths <- sapply(df[chv], function(v) max(nchar(v), na.rm=T))
        if (any(lengths > len)) {
            warning(paste("Clipped strings in", names(df[chv]), "to", len, "characters"))
            for (v in which(chv)) {
                df[[v]] = substr(df[[v]], start=1, stop=len)
            }
        }
        lengths[is.infinite(lengths)] = 0
        lengths[lengths < 1] = 1
        lengths <- paste("(A", lengths, ")", sep = "")
        # star <- ifelse(c(FALSE, diff(which(chv) > 1)), " *",
        dl.varnames[chv] <- paste(dl.varnames[chv], lengths)
    }

    # decimals and bools
    nmv = sapply(df, is.numeric)
    dbv = sapply(df, is.numeric)
    nv = (nmv | dbv)
    decimals = sapply(df[nv], FUN=decimalplaces)
    dl.varnames[nv] = paste(dl.varnames[nv], " (F", decimals+8, ".", decimals, ")", sep="")
    if (length(bv) > 0) {
        dl.varnames[bv] = paste(dl.varnames[bv], "(F1.0)")
    }
    rmv = !(chv | nv | bv)
    if (length(rmv) > 0) {
        dl.varnames[rmv] = paste(dl.varnames[rmv], "(F8.0)")
    }
    # Breaks in output
    brv = seq(1, length(dl.varnames), 10)
    dl.varnames[brv] = paste(dl.varnames[brv], "\n", sep=" ")

    cat("SET LOCALE = ENGLISH.\n", file = codefile)
    cat("DATA LIST FILE=", adQuote(datafile), " free (TAB)\n", file = codefile, append = TRUE)
    cat("/", dl.varnames, " .\n\n", file = codefile, append = TRUE)
    cat("VARIABLE LABELS\n", file = codefile, append = TRUE)
    cat(paste(varnames, adQuote(varlabels), "\n"), ".\n", file = codefile,
        append = TRUE)
    factors <- sapply(df, is.factor)
    if (any(factors)) {
        cat("\nVALUE LABELS\n", file = codefile, append = TRUE)
        for (v in which(factors)) {
            cat("/\n", file = codefile, append = TRUE)
            cat(varnames[v], " \n", file = codefile, append = TRUE)
            levs <- levels(df[[v]])
            cat(paste(1:length(levs), adQuote(levs), "\n", sep = " "),
                file = codefile, append = TRUE)
        }
        cat(".\n", file = codefile, append = TRUE)
    }

    # Labels stored in attr()
    attribs <- !unlist(lapply(sapply(df, FUN=attr, which="1"), FUN=is.null))
    if (any(attribs)) {
        cat("\nVALUE LABELS\n", file = codefile, append = TRUE)
        for (v in which(attribs)) {
            cat("/\n", file = codefile, append = TRUE)
            cat(varnames[v], " \n", file = codefile, append = TRUE)
            # Check labeled values
            tc = list()
            for (tcv in dimnames(table(df[[v]]))[[1]]) {
                if (!is.null(tcl <- attr(df[[v]], tcv))) {
                    tc[tcv] = tcl
                }
            }
            cat(paste(names(tc), tc, "\n", sep = " "),
                file = codefile, append = TRUE)
        }
        cat(".\n", file = codefile, append = TRUE)
    }

    ordinal <- sapply(df, is.ordered)
    if (any(ordinal)) {
        tmp = varnames[ordinal]
        brv = seq(1, length(tmp), 10)
        tmp[brv] = paste(tmp[brv], "\n")
        cat(paste("\nVARIABLE LEVEL", paste(tmp, collapse=" "), "(ORDINAL).\n"),
            file = codefile, append = TRUE)
    }
    num <- sapply(df, is.numeric)
    if (any(num)) {
        tmp = varnames[num]
        brv = seq(1, length(tmp), 10)
        tmp[brv] = paste(tmp[brv], "\n")
        cat(paste("\nVARIABLE LEVEL", paste(tmp, collapse=" "), "(SCALE).\n"),
            file = codefile, append = TRUE)
    }
    cat("\nEXECUTE.\n", file = codefile, append = TRUE)

    write.table(dfn, file = datafile, row = FALSE, col = FALSE,
                sep = "\t", quote = F, na = "", eol = "\n", fileEncoding="UTF-8")
}
```

On the long term, the changes might be considered to be merged into the `foreign`package. Unfortunately, the bug reporting system for the r-project is currently limited to previously registered developers.

Answer (score 1):

The SPSS extension command STATS GET R can read a data frame directly into an SPSS dataset from a saved R workspace.  If this extension command is not already installed (it will show up on the File menu), it can be installed from the Utilities menu (Statistics 22-23) or the Extensions menu (Statistics 24+).

Comment: Path for German SPSS Version 23: Extras -> Erweiterungsbundles -> Erweiterungsbundles herunterladen und installieren (STATS GET R). Additionally, the "Integration Plug-in for R" (part of the "Essentials for R") must be installed (http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/de/SSLVMB_22.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/spss/base/faq_plugins.htm - IBM registration required). Note that the SPSS essentials require a specific R version (e.g, 3.1) and will download several R packages during the installation (be patient). Value and variable labels were missing after import, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

What I've found is that:

1. 'foreign' can't handle values with commas in them (basically, it fails what Excel can do with .csv files).
2. 'haven' demands SPSS-compatible names in the r data set.

What I did for the latter is rename them as haven found them.
It seemed to work in blocks:
'Initial 1' through 'Initial 4'
'Final 1' through 'Final 4'
'relapse' and 'Relapse'.